I can't move an object or selected vertices unless locked to an Axis
I've been working on this project for a long while without this issue ever popping up- but now, when i try to select an object while in object mode, or even certain points while in edit mode, I can not move them unless I select a view axis. (So the X, Y, Z options in the top right corner).
I have been using G to move things around, is it possible that I've messed up one of the project settings? I have already tried resetting to default preferences, and I can confirm that moving objects or vertices in any other project works just fine.
Edit: Correction to the original, I can move them, but its a long distance snappy type movement. No fine motor control or the abillity to barely nudge objects/vertices in the desired direction.

I've figured it out! I had the Magnet icon selected towards the top.
